# Elevation data for settlements

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, elevation

I'm new to QGIS, and I'm trying to plot settlements on a map with their elevation data (using Openstreetmap). Problem is, I find most of the villages/ towns have their 'ele' data missing in the attribute table. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You can get an elevation raster and join the villages with it. Whats your area of interest? A free source (almost) worldwide is SRTM.

Comment: @MrXsquared I'm looking at the Tibetan plateau, hence it's a large area. Is there a way to get all that SRTM in a go?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/cbanddataproducts.html

Comment: @TimothyDalton Thanks. Do you have an idea how to bulk download multiple SRTM grids together?

Comment: Some more information to be found here https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/elevation.md

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using [SRTM Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission):

First, install [SRTM-Downloader Plugin for QGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SRTM-Downloader/) and create an account for "Earthdata Login" at https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov//users/new

Start the Plugin, choose your desired extent and click "Download":

[image]

Once the process is finished, merge them to one big raster, you can join your points with. Go to "Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build virtual raster". Select all just downloaded rasters as input and unselect "Place each input into a separate band". Then hit "Run":

[image]

Dont worry if it takes some time to load/display the virtual raster, this may take some time depending on its size. Now run "Sample raster values" from processing toolbox. Choose your villages as input and your virtual raster as raster. Add a column name:

[image]

Done:

[image]